# Unexpected White space & Values in bar plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar ploy using `plt.bar()`:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(10,50,11)
plt.bar(x, y, color = "blue", alpha=0.2)
```

the output is the following:
[image]

However, my x-values should only range from 0 to 1. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the bars get a width of `0.8` measured on the x-axis, assuming the values have a spacing of `1.0`. When the distances between the subsequent x-values is different, a width can be explicitly set, for example like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
y = np.linspace(10, 50, 11)
relative_barwidth = 0.9
barwidth = relative_barwidth * (x[1] - x[0])
plt.bar(x, y, width=barwidth, color="blue")
plt.xticks(x) # set a tick mark for every x-value 
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

Review the documentation for bar.  You're specifying the placement of the center of each bar on the x-axis and its height, the width is not being supplied by you and so it's defaulting to 0.8.